# How to reinstall dnsmasq-base

Tags: 12.04, network-manager

I accidentally removed dnsmasq-base following a tutorial without looking at the warnings in the comments. So what I want to know is, is there a way of getting my network manager back without losing any of my data?

Comment: Can you connect to the Internet via a wired interface (connecting the Ethernet cable)? Read this [NetworkConfiguration](http://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Setting_up_an_Ethernet_Interface), specially the manual configuration of Ethernet, I think might help.

Comment: Hi. Are you able to connect to the internet by plugging into a wired connection? You may need to do some terminal work. Do you still have dhclient?

Comment: What tutorial were you following and what command did you run ?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/191226/dnsmasq-failed-to-create-listening-socket-for-port-53-address-already-in-use

That is the question that I followed without looking at comments.

Comment: ethernet cable doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can use a chroot from a live cd to install a package from a non-bootable/no network system. [Follow this guide](http://karuppuswamy.com/wordpress/2010/06/02/how-to-chroot-to-ubuntu-using-live-cd-to-fix-grub-rescue-prompt/) up to step six (do step six, but NOT 7).  I know the guide is for rearing grub but the chroot process is what we are interested in.

Once you have done that, you should be able to just do a `sudo apt-get install dnsmasq`
and reboot.

Comment: The link seems to be missing.

Comment: In The tutorial on step 5, for all the commands it just comes up telling me the usage of the mount command. I ignored this unsure whether it had executed the command. Then when i run the final command on this answer it sayss it is already installed but asks if i want to continue, i put yes and it gives me an error. Please help.
Thanks Again, Ryan

Comment: Okay, i got it fixed. I did this by adding in the command 
"sudo apt-get install network-manager"
After mounting everything.

Thanks Again,
Ryan

Answer (score 1):

You can download the removed packages from:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=dnsmasq-base

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=network-manager

download also: network-manager-gnome (I cannot post 3 links)

Choose the right package according to your distro:
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS:Precise Pangolin
Ubuntu 12.10: Quantal Quetzal
Ubuntu 13.04: Raring Ringtail

Copy those files to an USB stick. Start your Linux OS and copy the files of the USB stick to a folder.

Open terminal an go to the folder.

Then install using:

```
sudo dpkg -i <package name>
```

After that, restart network manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

I hope that helps!