# Correct way to set DNS

Tags: networking, dns

I have a DNS server running on my computer, and I want Ubuntu to use it to resolve addresses. I've setup mydomain.com as a custom domain

I went into Network settings, switched to manual in 'Wired', entered my IP, Gateway, Mask. And then I entered my IP in the DNS field.

How do I cause this to take effect? `dig @myiphere mydomain.com` works, but `dig mydomain.com` doesn't return any address.

If I edit `/etc/resolv.conf` by hand and change the first line from `127.0.1.1` to `myiphere`, then everything starts to work.

But this doesn't seem to be the right way to do things as `resolv.conf` warns against manual changes by hand.

So how do I PROPERLY and reliably change DNS?

Comment: Possibly releated to default dnsmasq configuration running in desktop installation? http://askubuntu.com/questions/191226/dnsmasq-failed-to-create-listening-socket-for-port-53-address-already-in-use/279539#279539

Answer (score 0):

I would expect your network manager settings to apply and take care of resolv.conf.

You can alternatively manage this interface from /etc/network/interfaces, with a configuration similar to this one (example taken from "man resolvconf"):

```
iface eth0 inet static
               address 192.168.1.3
               netmask 255.255.255.0
               gateway 192.168.1.1
               dns-nameservers 192.168.1.254 8.8.8.8
               dns-search foo.org bar.com
```